# building web service APIs that back mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, web-services, rest, soap

I have been tasked with building web service APIs that back mobile apps. My question is, what can we do to make a web service more specialized for mobile apps? I know that REST/JSON is preferred... but that's all I know.. is there anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be:

1. Design the UI of the app and determine what data should be provided for each UI. Just draw something on papers or use story board if you want.
2. Design APIs according to step 1. If your app is simple enough, you can design one URL for one UI. You can take twitter's API as an example.

That's how I did in my graduation project. But the story may be totally different in companies.